# I got stuck trying to fetch the previous value based on a criteria

Tags: feature-extraction, featuretools

I'm new to FeatureTools library, and I got stuck trying to create two types of features, both are related to fetching previous values. One is the previous value itself for  `'QUANTIDADE'`, `'VALOR_TOTAL'` and `'DATA_NOTA'`, and the other is the time since the previous observation (days) which has `'DATA_NOTA'` as the date field.

I don't know if it is possible to do it with FeaturelTools. If someone can help me, I would appreciate it.

I have a dataframe (df) as folowing:
[image]

When I normalize the above df it takes the following basic schema:

[image]

As I said, I would like to fetch the previous values and time since the last observation for  `'QUANTIDADE'`, `'VALOR_TOTAL'` and `'DATA_NOTA'`, but when the combination of `'CODIGO_PRODUTO'` and `'CODIGO_CLIENTE'` matches.