# FeatureTools GroupBy issue excluding entities

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, feature-extraction, featuretools

This question is a follow-up of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58701802/i-got-stuck-trying-to-fetch-the-previous-value-based-on-a-criteria?answertab=oldest#tab-top):

I could solve the first part of the doubt but after that, another arose.

I have the following Featuretools entity set:
[image]

And I would like to get the `groupby_trans_primitives`: `Diff` and `TimeSincePrevious`(days), but just in the recordings entity, excluding other entities: `'vendedores','produtos',cliente','produto_cliente'`

I tried the following code to exclude those entities unsuccessfully:

```
from featuretools.primitives import TimeSincePrevious
time_since_previous = TimeSincePrevious(unit = "days")

fm, features = ft.dfs(entityset=es, 
                      target_entity='recordings',
                      trans_primitives = [],
                      agg_primitives = [],
                      max_depth=2,
                      verbose=True,
                      groupby_trans_primitives=['Diff',time_since_previous],
                      primitive_options={'time_since_previous': {'ignore_groupby_entities': ['vendedores','produtos','cliente']}})
```

Because the code returned de following features:

```
Built 38 features
Elapsed: 00:38 | Progress: 100%|██████████
[<Feature: CODIGO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: NOME_VENDEDOR>,
 <Feature: CODIGO_PRODUTO>,
 <Feature: QUANTIDADE>,
 <Feature: VALOR_TOTAL>,
 <Feature: PRODUTO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: DIFF(QUANTIDADE) by PRODUTO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: DIFF(QUANTIDADE) by CODIGO_PRODUTO>,
 <Feature: DIFF(QUANTIDADE) by NOME_VENDEDOR>,
 <Feature: DIFF(QUANTIDADE) by CODIGO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: DIFF(VALOR_TOTAL) by PRODUTO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: DIFF(VALOR_TOTAL) by CODIGO_PRODUTO>,
 <Feature: DIFF(VALOR_TOTAL) by NOME_VENDEDOR>,
 <Feature: DIFF(VALOR_TOTAL) by CODIGO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(DATA_NOTA, unit=days) by PRODUTO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(DATA_NOTA, unit=days) by CODIGO_PRODUTO>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(DATA_NOTA, unit=days) by NOME_VENDEDOR>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(DATA_NOTA, unit=days) by CODIGO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: cliente.CLASSIFICACAO>,
 <Feature: cliente.REDE>,
 <Feature: cliente.CIDADE>,
 <Feature: cliente.UF>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(vendedores.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by PRODUTO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(vendedores.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_PRODUTO>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(vendedores.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by NOME_VENDEDOR>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(vendedores.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produto_cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by PRODUTO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produto_cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_PRODUTO>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produto_cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by NOME_VENDEDOR>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produto_cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by PRODUTO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_PRODUTO>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by NOME_VENDEDOR>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produtos.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by PRODUTO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produtos.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_PRODUTO>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produtos.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by NOME_VENDEDOR>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produtos.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_CLIENTE>]
```

And I don't know why the following features were created as my code specified to exclude those entities:

```
<Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(vendedores.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by PRODUTO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(vendedores.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_PRODUTO>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(vendedores.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by NOME_VENDEDOR>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(vendedores.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produto_cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by PRODUTO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produto_cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_PRODUTO>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produto_cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by NOME_VENDEDOR>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produto_cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by PRODUTO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_PRODUTO>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by NOME_VENDEDOR>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(cliente.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produtos.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by PRODUTO_CLIENTE>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produtos.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_PRODUTO>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produtos.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by NOME_VENDEDOR>,
 <Feature: TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produtos.first_recordings_time, unit=days) by CODIGO_CLIENTE>]
```

I would appreciate any kind of help! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually a bug with how `primitive_options` ignores entities that will get fixed in the next release of featuretools, but for now you can filter out those features by keeping those primitive options and adding a `drop_contains` filter

```
fm, features = ft.dfs(entityset=es, 
                      target_entity='recordings',
                      trans_primitives = [],
                      agg_primitives = [],
                      max_depth=2,
                      verbose=True,
                      groupby_trans_primitives=['Diff',time_since_previous],
                      drop_contains=["TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produtos.", "TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(cliente.", "TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(produto_cliente.", "TIME_SINCE_PREVIOUS(vendedores."],
                      primitive_options={'time_since_previous': {'ignore_groupby_entities': ['vendedores','produtos','cliente']}})
```

Once the next release is out we will update the answer to work without `drop_contains`

Comment: Thank you @Roy Wedge! I'm looking forward to the next release.